# Spring Boot: handling requests for two different hosts

Tags: spring

I created a public page for searching books, and a management page to add books. I have a controller class as such (constructor ignored):

```
@RequestMapping("/books")
@RestController
public class BookController{
  private BookService bookService;

  @PostMapping("")
  public Book addBookUsingManagementConsole(@RequestBody BookAdd newBook) {
    //... stub
    // should map to http://management.com/api/post/books
  }

  @GetMapping("")
  public Book searchBooksUsingPublicPage(@RequestParam(name="name") String name) {
    //... stub
    // should map to http://publicpage.com/api/get/books
  }

}
```

Now I wanted to map these functions to different hosts. Should I use:

```
@RestController
public class BookController{
  private BookService bookService;

  @PostMapping("http://management.com/api/post/books")
  public Book addBookUsingManagementConsole(@RequestBody BookAdd newBook) {
    //... stub
    // should map to http://management.com/api/post/books
  }

  @GetMapping("http://publicpage.com/api/get/books")
  public Book searchBooksUsingPublicPage(@RequestParam(name="name") String name) {
    //... stub
    // should map to http://publicpage.com/api/get/books
  }

}
```

or do I need to do something else?

Comment: That won't work. Either write 2 applications which deploy to different hosts, or do a single host and add security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different headers to navigate the request from different host.

```
@PostMapping(value="api/post/books",headers = "Host=management.com")
headers = "Accept=application/json"
  public Book addBookUsingManagementConsole(@RequestBody BookAdd newBook) {
    //... stub
    // should map to http://management.com/api/post/books
  }

  @GetMapping(value="api/get/books",headers = "Host=publicpage.com")
  public Book searchBooksUsingPublicPage(@RequestParam(name="name") String name) {
    //... stub
    // should map to http://publicpage.com/api/get/books
  }
```